# How to remove a referenced table in lua?

Tags: lua

How would I go around removing a table I referenced to to clear the memory?

E.g.

```
a = { "a" }
b = a

-- Removing a, by only using b
```

Setting b to nil would just remove the reference, so how would I delete the table it refers to, by only using b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

If someone has a reference to that table, then they have a reference to it. Lua does not give you the power to unilaterally remove other people's stuff.

Now, you can try to do this, by having someone use a table indirectly:

```
a = {{"a"}}
b = a
a[1][1] == "a" --How to access the table.
b[1] = nil
a[1][1] == "a" --Runtime failure, due to `nil` access.
```

Typically, such uses are given names rather than numbers:

```
a = {name = {"a"}}
b = a
a.name[1] == "a" --How to access the table.
b.name = nil
a.name[1] == "a" --Runtime failure, due to `nil` access.
```

But either way, this won't stop someone from doing this:

```
a = {name = {"a"}}
b = a
local c = a.name --Local storage
a.name[1] == "a" --How to access the table.
b.name = nil
c[1] == "a" --Still works
```

Lua does not have the power to, *in general*, allow you to reach into other people's data and play with their stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that alternative example was very helpful!

Comment: In theory you could manually search over **everything** to find references and disconnect them. There's no practical usage for this though.

Comment: Why do you keep referencing this as 'access to other peoples stuff'?? It has nothing to do with the question. Are you trying to reapply the purpose of the question to the access and manipulation of other peoples data? That is completely inappropriate, has nothing to do with the question itself.

Comment: @kite: That's what the question *is*. There are two variables: `a` and `b`. They are variables that both hold the same data. The user wants to perform an operation on variable `b` such that it affects variable `a`. If you had access to `a`, you wouldn't ask the question, since you could just *modify `a`*. Therefore, `a` must be "other people's data". And the OP seems to agree, since they accepted the answer.